# Where is the carriage return character?

Tags: windows, regex, newlines, carriage-return

I am confused about the carriage return character `\r` in Windows.

As everybody knows, Windows uses CRLF, i.e. `\r\n`, to terminate lines. So I thought, and tested it out. I opened Visual Studio Code, created a new text file, entered a line, like so:

[image]

I made sure the line ending is set to `CRLF` in the bottom right:

[image]

Now I press `Ctrl+f` to search for `\n` using regex, and as expected there is a newline at the end of that line:

[image]

So far so good, but when I now search for the `\r` character, nothing is found!

[image]

But since the line ending is set to CRLF, shouldn't it find a `\r` right before the `\n`? This confuses me terribly. What is going on here?

Comment: Carriage returns may not be part of the editor buffer.

Comment: Open the file with a hex editor and see what you have,

Comment: In many cases, `\n` is used to represent the *concept* of a newline (which might have different representations on different platforms) and does not always mean a literal linefeed character.

Comment: @John yea it's there of course but why is it not there in the VS Code editor, why would they filter it out

Comment: I am not sure about the VS Code part.

Comment: @csstudent1418 Because treating `\n` as a newline in a regular expression is what people want to do 99.99...% of the time.  Treating `\n` as a literal linefeed character and forcing all people editing Windows files to use `\r\n` would be a significant inconvenience and would be error-prone.

Comment: From @John `Open the file with a hex editor and see what you have` .. this is the first thing that I would do also.  Look for 0x0D 0x0A. or simply 0D0A

Comment: @jamesdlin You might have misunderstood me. Sure treat `\n` as a newline in a regex but why not `\r` as well? That's my question, I am fine with how visual studio works regarding `\n`

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas But my doubt was not about `\r` existing in the file (it does), rather about why VS Code doesn't find it when searching for it using Regex.

Comment: It is possible that the in memory buffer doesn't bother with the /r.. strips them on load and only assigns it on save.  I would have to look at the source and that would take a long time to find.

Comment: After looking at the source code.. it looks like what I said was on the money.  The lines you are looking at in the editor were split using a line like this one `this._lines = contents.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);` and all handled the same within the editor.  There are also language specific parsers that might handle this differently but I don't have time to read them.

Comment: Your complaint is with the tool, i.e., VSC, not with the EOL characters. As others have stated, use an appropriate tool, such as Notepad++ or HxD Hex Editor. Windows does, indeed, expect \r\n at end of line, though some Windows applications will also recognize and display Linux and old Mac EOL conventions correctly. Hmm... what are the EBCDIC conventions?